# Visual Studio 2010 on windows 8

Tags: .net-framework, visual-studio-2010, windows-8

I'm working on VS2010 and Windows 8. whenever I run the application windows starts flickering which is quite weird.

I tried following things but didn't get any help out of it.

> ```
> Open Tools/Options dialog
> In the options tree select the Environment/General page.
> Uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" 
> then uncheck "Enable rich client visual experience" checkboxes.
> Close the Tools/Options dialog
> ```

and I also tried making some changes in regedit.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does Visual Studio 2012 run ok? Also, do other applications work ok? Specifically, do Youtube videos play ok?

Comment: I didn't check with VS2012 but other apps working as expected without any issues.
regarding you tube no issues.
FYI -> I have RAM of 16 GB.

Comment: It's probably more of a Superuser question, I've had no issues running VS 2010 on Windows 8

Comment: what would you suggest?

Comment: Did you install both Visual Studio 2010's Service Pack 1, and the Windows 8 update for it? See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/02/microsoft-update-for-visual-studio-2010-sp1-with-compatibility-support-for-visual-studio-2012-and-windows-8.aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182

Comment: yes I have installed but still having issue.Update 2736182

Comment: any suggestion guys?